# Display the method of payment of an order on the invoice pdf comerce billy

Tags: 7, commerce

I installed [Commerce Billy](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_billy).

How can I display the payment method on my bill?

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Template for invoiced orders.
 */

?>
<?php
//The code to get payment type

$order_id = $content['commerce_customer_billing']['#object']->order_id;

$payment_method = '';
$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
$r = explode('|', $order->data['payment_method']);

if (count($r) > 1){
  $rule = rules_config_load($r[1]);
  $payment_method = $rule->label;
}
?>
<div class="invoice-invoiced">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="<?php print $content['invoice_logo']['#value']; ?>"/>
    <div class="invoice-header">
        <p><?php print render($content['invoice_header']); ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr/>

  <div class="customer-billing"><?php print render($content['commerce_customer_billing']); ?></div>
  <div class="customer-shipping"><?php print render($content['commerce_customer_shipping']); ?></div>
  <h1 class="credit-memo"><?php print render($content['invoice_title']); ?></h1>
  <div class="invoice-header-date"><?php print render($content['invoice_header_date']); ?></div>
  <div class="order-id"><?php print render($content['order_id']); ?></div>


  <?php print($payment_method); // Use this PHP Code where you want to print the payment type, you can style it any way, adding div, span, whatever you want ?>     


  <div class="line-items">
    <div class="line-items-view"><?php print render($content['commerce_line_items']); ?></div>
    <div class="order-total"><?php print render($content['commerce_order_total']); ?></div>
  </div>
  <div class="invoice-text"><?php print render($content['invoice_text']); ?></div>

  <div class="invoice-footer"><?php print render($content['invoice_footer']); ?></div>
</div>
```

Here are the contents of my file "commerce_order--commerce_order--pdf.tpl.php".
Where do I put the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code below to get the payment method of an order by passing order id to the function. The order id on Commerce billy template file can be easily found in this variable *$content['commerce_customer_billing']['#object']->order_id* and some other variables as well:

```
$order_id = $content['commerce_customer_billing']['#object']->order_id;

$payment_method = '';
$order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
$r = explode('|', $order->data['payment_method']);

if (count($r) > 1){
  $rule = rules_config_load($r[1]);
  $payment_method = $rule->label;
}
```

After using this function, you can print the payment method on your bill by printing *$payment_method* variable.

Comment: thank you, but I'm not very good in code. Where to put this code?

Comment: You need to put it into "commerce_order--commerce_order--pdf.tpl.php" file which you will find under under your commerce billy module at path "commerce_billy/modules/commerce_billy_pdf/templates". If you are a bit technical, then instead of making changes here, you may override this template in your theme folder, it need to copy this file to your theme folder and do some configuration through UI. If you are not so technical that make changes to current file.

Comment: @user60884 : if you're 'not very good in code", then you should include that in your actual question somehow. E.g. by adding something like "I do not want to write any custom code".

Comment: @drupaler : I updated my question. So I copy the "commerce_order--commerce_order--pdf.tpl.php" file in the templates folder of my theme, can you give me more details ?

Comment: I have updated the code in the question, please check